# Grep command list bin/bash or dash

Tags: bash, unix, grep

Is there a grep command that lists all users (in /etc/passwd) who use either bash (/bin/bash) or dash (/bin/sh) and their home directory is in /home (second to last section of: has home directory)?

I am thinking of commands:

```
getent passwd | awk -F ':' '$6 ~ "^/home" {print $1}'
```

or :

```
getent passwd| awk -F ":" '$7=="/bin/bash" { print $1 }'
```

but I am wrong.

Comment: Were you thinking of something like this? `awk -F: '{if ($6 ~ "/home/" && ($7 ~ "/bin/bash" || $7 ~ "/bin/sh")) {print $0} }' /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0):

Just combine your conditions:

```
getent passwd | awk -F':' '$7 ~ "^/bin/(ba)?sh$" && $6 ~ "^/home/"{ print $1 }'
```

or

```
getent passwd | awk -F':' '($7=="/bin/bash" || $7=="/bin/sh") && $6 ~ "^/home/"{ print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

The grep command that satisfies your conditions is as follows:

```
   getent passwd | grep -E ':/home/.*?:.*?[bd]ash$'
```

The regex is all the lines with a home directory and bash or dash.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25669710)

Comment: @veben : Why do you think that the answer by GabrielLaden does not answer the original question? Admittedly it outputs not just the user names, but the whole passwd lines, but how to get the user name out of this is trivial and, as I conclude from the question, already understood by the OP.